# How to track DML operation without using triggers

Tags: trigger, workflow, scheduled-apex

I am trying to insert/update/delete/undelete records of opportunity team into custom object.This should be acheived without using any Trigger on Opportunity Team.
     generalizing my question; how can i track a dml operation on object without using trigger(In trigger we track using .isInsert/.isUpdate).

Comment: It'll help if you express why you can not use triggers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workflow rule and have it fire whenever a record is created and/or updated.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/_app/video/workflow/help/create_workflow_rule.jsp

Comment: but what if I delete/undelete the record,then i cannot track fields.please support me with any way to acheive this.I heard it can be done using apexschedule.

Comment: Hi Seepana, I see you've clarified your question. Originally it seemed you were only interested in create/update events, which workflows can support. Only triggers/apex can detect when records are deleted. Apex Scheduling has nothing to do with detecting these events.

Answer (score 0):

Set the debug logs and perform the operations. Debug logs are a very efficient way of tracking each and every thing that happens in your org. Right from invocation of the constructor method till finishing all other methods, it records everything.
P.S. The DML can be found under the tags `Op: Insert/Update` etc. next to it is the object name under `Type:` tag. Also you can see the number of rows that are affected by the operation.

Comment: thanks Saket Joshi...I learnt a new thing though i didnt expect answer from this perspective.